# JAVAFX SwingFXUtils.fromFXImag method dosen't return

Tags: java, javafx, io

SwingFXUtils.fromFXImag method dosen't return - and appears to be in some kind of deadlock - excution not stopping and no exception is thrown.

Heres the code:

```
    package test;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;



public class Test extends javafx.application.Application {

    static    FileOutputStream fos;
    static BufferedImage bi;
    static WritableImage wi;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

     try{
        WritableImage wi=new WritableImage(500,500);
        }catch(Exception e){;}


     Button button2 = new Button("Accept");
     wi = new WritableImage(500,500);
     wi = button2.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);

     bi = new BufferedImage(500,500,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
     bi= (BufferedImage)SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(wi, null);
    }



    public static void main(String [] args){


    try{
    File file = new File("c:\test.png");
    file.createNewFile();
    file.setReadable(true);
    fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
    ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", fos);
    }
    catch(IOException e){}


    }

}
```

In debugger I put a breakpoint on all lines of the program. It pauses on:
 bi= (BufferedImage)SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(wi, null);
and does not continue - though the program is still in running state.

The program has no output or errors.

Comment: It can not output any errors because your catch blocks are all Empty. What do you think happens to errors when you ignore them?

Comment: And then \ needs to be escaped to \\ in that string literal file name.

Comment: Are you sure the method blocks? It is the last call in your `start` method, and the program won't exit because you have started the FX toolkit. If you put something like a `System.out.println("Test");` after that method, does it progress to it? What if you put a `Platform.exit()` there? (As an aside, why are you repeatedly initializing all your variables? You assign `wi` three different times and do nothing with it in between each assignment.)

Comment: Your `main` method does not make much sense. If you call it directly, you'd get a exception, since `bi` is `null`. (You never invoke `Application.launch` and the `start` method would fill the field.) Furthermore you're creating 3 images that you simply "throw away" without using them 2x`wi=new WritableImage(500,500);` + `bi = new BufferedImage(500,500,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);`. Furthermore if you do launch `Test` as an application javafx will wait for a window to be opened and then exit the platform after windows have been closed, which doesn't happen since you never show a window.

Comment: Thank you. Platform.exit() did the trick